# How to make Haskell use whole processor power while compiling

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I noticed that when I do compilation, installing some module, `haskell` compiler uses only one processor (blue chart 1/4)? 1 of 4 on my laptop.

I've heard that Haskell Compiler is smart, so it could safe my time using all I have.

Is there a way to make it faster? Some configuration maybe.

There is a pic - processor graph is blue. Yellow - network. Red - hard-drive.

At that moment when screenshot was made it could use all processor time since it does not use either hard-drive or network.

[image]

Comment: Note that, as full as your _memory_ looks, fully exploiting all cores might not be such a great idea since this tends to also cost more RAM. It might drive the compilation into swap, effectively making it substantially _slower_!

Comment: Green - memory. Light green - cached / not active memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the `-j` flag in [GHC versions 7.8.1 and higher](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc1/html/users_guide/release-7-8-1.html).